# How to catch errors with flutter grpc Interceptor

Tags: flutter, dart, grpc, interceptor

I try to implement authentication in flutter with grpc (with protobuf) and Interceptors. I'm now stuck on handling an expired accessToken, where I would like to refresh the token and refresh the token. After the refresh, the function should get called again, so the actually function wont notice the expired token.

This is my AuthClient

```
 final channel = ClientChannel(
        grpcHost,
        port: grpcPort,
        options: ChannelOptions(
          credentials: const ChannelCredentials.insecure(),
          codecRegistry:
              CodecRegistry(codecs: const [GzipCodec(), IdentityCodec()]),
        ),
      );
      _client = AuthServiceClient(channel,
          interceptors: [AuthenticationInterceptor()]);
```

The AuthClient is using this ClientInterceptor

```dart
class AuthenticationInterceptor extends ClientInterceptor {
  final storage = const FlutterSecureStorage();

  FutureOr<void> _provider(Map<String, String> metadata, String uri) async {
    final accessToken = await storage.read(key: 'accessToken');
    metadata['Authorization'] = accessToken ?? "";
  }

  @override
  ResponseFuture<R> interceptUnary<Q, R>(
      ClientMethod<Q, R> method, Q request, CallOptions options, invoker) {
    return super.interceptUnary(method, request,
        options.mergedWith(CallOptions(providers: [_provider])), invoker)
      ..catchError((e) async {
        if (e is GrpcError) {
          if (e.code == StatusCode.invalidArgument &&
              e.message == "Invalid auth token") {
            await refreshTheToken();

            return super.interceptUnary(
                method,
                request,
                options.mergedWith(CallOptions(providers: [_provider])),
                invoker);
          }
        }
        throw e;
      });
  }
}
```

I call the client like this

```dart
loadUser() async {
    print("Loading user");
    _status = AuthStatus.uninitialized;

    try {
      StatusRequest statusRequest = StatusRequest();
      final status = await _client!.status(statusRequest);
      _status = AuthStatus.authenticated;
      _currentUser = User(status.user.id, status.user.username);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      _status = AuthStatus.unauthenticated;
    } finally {
      notifyListeners();
    }
  }
```

I expected with the `await refreshTheToken();` and the `return super.interceptUnary` I could refresh the token and then call the function again, without getting an error in the `loadUser` function.

The actual behavior is however that the `loadUser` function throws an error, before the `catchError` in the `interceptUnary` can handle the error and refresh the token.